# How to read the pdf file using selenium

Tags: java, pdf, selenium-webdriver, download, pdf-reader

I am working on web page over which there is a link, clicking on which it opens a pdf file on new window. 
I have to read that pdf file to validate some data against the transactions done. One way is to download that file and then use it. 
Can any one help me out on this. I have to work on IE 11

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: reading content from pdf using selenium won't work. Download the pdf file and than read the file using PDFbox or any other library.

Answer (score 4):

Use PDFBox and FontBox.

```
    public String readPDFInURL() throws EmptyFileException, IOException {
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        // page with example pdf document
        driver.get("file:///C:/Users/admin/Downloads/dotnet_TheRaceforEmpires.pdf");
        URL url = new URL(driver.getCurrentUrl());
        InputStream is = url.openStream();
        BufferedInputStream fileToParse = new BufferedInputStream(is);
        PDDocument document = null;
        try {
            document = PDDocument.load(fileToParse);
            String output = new PDFTextStripper().getText(document);
        } finally {
            if (document != null) {
                document.close();
            }
            fileToParse.close();
            is.close();
        }
        return output;
    }
```

Since some of the functions from the older versions of PDFBox have been deprecated, we need to use another FontBox along with PDFBox. I have used [PDFBox (2.0.3)](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.pdfbox/pdfbox/2.0.3) and [FontBox (2.0.3)](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.pdfbox/fontbox) and it is working fine. It won't read images though.

Comment: Not sure if this works with the current version; better do `PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(url.openStream());` and then delete all the unneeded code (COSDocument, PDFParser)

Comment: Try the following function:

Answer (score 1):

First Downlaod  pdfbox jar.

strURL is a web URl which contains .pdf file: 
like(https://example.com/downloads/presence/Online-Presence-CA-05-02-2017-04-13.pdf)

```
public boolean verifyPDFContent(String strURL, String text) {

        String output ="";
        boolean flag = false;
        try{
            URL url = new URL(strURL);
            BufferedInputStream file = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
            PDDocument document = null;
            try {
                document = PDDocument.load(file);
                output = new PDFTextStripper().getText(document);
                System.out.println(output);
            } finally {
                if (document != null) {
                    document.close();
                }
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if(output.contains(text)){
            flag =  true;
        }
        return flag;
    }
```

Comment: In my case the URL doesnt ends with .pdf how can i proceed

Comment: Please share your pdf