# how to read the pdf contents from browser Selenium C#

Tags: c#, pdf, selenium-webdriver

I am automating below scenario:

- click on a button,
- A pdf file is opened in new window
- read the content of pdf file which is opened in new window.

Help needed: After switching to window where pdf is opened, I have no idea how to proceed.

Note: this file cannot be downloaded.

Have tried the following

```
public void verifypdf()
{
    var browerTabs = driver.WindowHandles;
    Assert.True(browerTabs.Count > 0, "Form not open in new Window");
    driver.SwitchTo().Window(browerTabs[1]);
    string PdfUrl = driver.Url;
    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
    string test = readPDFContent(PdfUrl);
    driver.Close();
    driver.SwitchTo().Window(browerTabs[0]);
}

public String readPDFContent(String pdfUrl)
{
    Uri uri = new Uri(pdfUrl);

    //how to proceed from here??
```

Comment: Please clarify - what do you mean by "read the content of pdf file"? Extract text, get screenshot? If you need to parse some content then you _must_ download the file.

Comment: I am reading the text . And I don't think its mandatory to download the file as in JAVA this content can be read without downloading the file so same should be possible in C# also, correct me if I am wrong

Comment: Probably you used some PDF library in Java that downloaded PDF content implicitly. You need to download the file contents in any case, programming language does not matter here. For example, how it looks in Java: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40738373/how-to-read-the-pdf-file-using-selenium I've submitted C# code sample to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get full PDF content and then use some PDF library to extract text.

Here is the sample code using standard .NET WebClient class and [Docotic.Pdf library](https://bitmiracle.com/pdf-library/):

```cs
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    byte[] data = client.DownloadData(pdfUrl);
    using (var pdf = new PdfDocument(data))
    {
        string text = pdf.GetText();
        ... // do something with extracted text
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//download file to local machine:
//default downliad path in win: Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("USERPROFILE") + @"\Downloads\";

    using System.Net;
    using System.IO;
    public static class FileDownloader
        {
            public static string Download(this string downloadFrom,string fileName = "newFile.pdf", string downloadTo = "")
            {
                if (downloadTo.Length == 0) { downloadTo = BrowserConfig.DownloadsPath; }
                using var client = new WebClient();
                // Download data.
                var arr = client.DownloadData(downloadFrom);
                File.WriteAllBytes(downloadTo+ "\\" + fileName, arr);
                return downloadTo+fileName;
            }
        }

//read

    using System;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Net;
    using System.Text;
    using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
    using iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser;
    
            public static string ReadPdfFile(this string fileName)
            {
                StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
                Byte[] bytes;
    
                var wc = WebRequest.Create(fileName);
                using (var response = wc.GetResponse())
                {
                    using (var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
                    {
                        bytes = iTextSharp.text.io.StreamUtil.InputStreamToArray(responseStream);
                        PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(bytes);
                        for (int page = 1; page <= pdfReader.NumberOfPages; page++)
                        {
                            ITextExtractionStrategy strategy = new SimpleTextExtractionStrategy();
    
                            string currentText = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(pdfReader, page, strategy);
    
                            currentText = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Encoding.Convert(Encoding.Default, Encoding.UTF8,
                                Encoding.Default.GetBytes(currentText)));
                            text.Append(currentText);
                            //Console.WriteLine(text);
                        }
                        pdfReader.Close();
                    }
                }
                return text.ToString();
            }
```

Comment: Please explain what your code does and how it does it.

Comment: Neither this nor the other answer is actually using Selenium. Does that mean Selenium is not needed to retrieve PDF files?